# Fish Flasher - Reading Bottom

Tags: fishing, electronic-gear, ice

When using a flasher type fish finder, a hard bottom is displayed as a wide red band on the screen indicating a good return signal. The wide red band in the picture below covers between 10 and 12 feet.

Exactly where is the bottom?  10 feet?  12 feet? or in the middle at 11 feet?

[image: Flasher display]

Comment: I have no idea what the answer, is but if you question is accurate what is the green band between 12 and 13 feet? Buried treasure, maybe?

Comment: James, I have the same question.  But etiquette suggests that I can only ask one question in each post.  If that isn't covered in an answer, I'll be asking another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom is at 10 feet.

Here is a diagram showing what things are showing.
[image: This image points out what you are seeing]

Here are a couple of links of for help in reading what the finder is showing you.
https://www.flwfishing.com/tips/2005-02-04-abcs-of-understanding-flashers-fish-finders-for-bass-fishing

http://www.vexilar.com/blog/2014/08/28/how-to-ice-fish-with-a-vexilar-flasher

The other colors below the bottom are coming from echos from your transducer going through the ground a little ways before bouncing back to you.  The hard red implies to me that you have a hard bottom with little silt.  If it was more like the above image, there is a little bit of muck and things at the bottom (or it could be plants).  Something that doesn't bounce sound waves very strongly (like rocks).